# Send dynamic array to function C++

Tags: c, memory, dynamic

I have an array, which is now static. This are the operations I do with it.
Firstly I create a two-dimensional array. Then I fill it in, using cycles. And then I send it to function, where there are also cycles which are used.
Here I 'd like to post some sample code, which is similar to mine.

```
bool picture[20][20]; //here's my array right now. Pretty ugly. Just for testing.
for (int y=0;y<Height;y++)
{
    for (int x=0;x<Width;x++)
    {
        if (treshold<middle)
        {
            picture[x][y]=1;
        }
        else
        {
            picture[x][y]=0;
        }
     }
}
//Here's an example of filling an array

leftk = left(picture,widthk, heightk); //That's how I use a function

int left(int picture[200][200],int row,int col)
{
    for (int x = 0;  x <=row-1; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y <=col-1 ;y++)
        {
            if (picture1[x][y]==1)
            {
                return x;
            }
        }
    }
}
//And that's the function itself
```

So here I need to switch my array to a dynamic one. That's how I declare my dynamic array

```
bool** picture=new bool*[size];
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        picture[i] = new bool[size];

//size is just a variable.
```

As for statically declared cycles, everything is very simple. Sending this array as a parameter to function.

I've already managed to create a dynamic array, it's simple. Then I fill it in with numbers. No problems here too. But I can't understand, how to send an array to function and moreover how to use it there.
Could you give me an exaple of modifying two-dimensional arrays in functions.
Sorry for such a newbie question. Hope someone will help.

By the way, class wrapping would be a bit confusing here, I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A function such as:

```
Process2DArray(int **pArray, int rowCount, int colCount)
```

Should suffice the needs assuming its a 2D array that is being operated on. Also, consider using `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` instead of a multidimensional array allocated manually. This approach will help prevent leaks. The second approach also lets you have jagged arrays.

Comment: This depends on how the array has been defined.  I'd generally prefer wrapping it in a class, because there is no simple solution otherwise.

Comment: @JamesKanze : Personally, I'd wrap it in a class or struct if its needed in multiple places or used frequently in the program. Otherwise for one-place uses a `vector<vector<int>>` would do fine don't you think?

Comment: Well, thank you very much, but I've already mentioned that wrapping it in class would be inconvenient. What's more, the array is used only once, so I hope I will escape classes. The first way you showed seems to be quite simple, but needs some explanation. Firstly, I'll post my static C code right now to describe the problem better. Then I will post the declaration of my array. Hope, this will help too. But unfortunately, then I need your help. The action of sending an array and recieving it in the function is still not bright enough.

Comment: @BhargavBhat Just a bit awkward to write.  `std::vector<std::vector<double> > a2d( rows, std::vector<double>( columns ) );`

Comment: @user1131662 The basic problem is that the traditional C style arrays are broken, and don't lend themselves to any good solutions.  That's why I'd recommend wrapping with a class for even a single use.

Comment: @JamesKanze : Yes. That's true, the syntax for using it is ugly.

Comment: @OP : You could pass the entire array by reference to the function as an in/out parameter. The updated function signature could be something along the lines of: `void Process2DArray(vector< vector<int> >& my2DArray)`.

Comment: Well, unfortunately it seems that there's no way except this std::vector<std::vector<int>>, which I haven't studied yet and the class wrapping, which would lead to a massive piece of code. Am I right?

Comment: @OP : Both the `vector<vector<int>>` and the wrapper class are functionally identical. Its just that the wrapper class method is more readable and easier to use if you need this kind of a data structure in multiple places. Also, as originally stated in my answer you can always do this with a plain old `int**`, just that its more prone to memory leaks and not very convenient.

Comment: @Bhargav Bhat so that gives me some hope. If I intend use `int**`, could you tell me what to put instead of `picture` here `leftk = left(picture,widthk, heightk);` and here `int left(int picture[200][200],int row,int col)`. And also, how should I use the variables **int row,int col** in the function so that it'd do the same thing?

Comment: @OP : Please change the function signature to `int left(int  **picture,int row,int col)`. Rest of your code looks fine. It should continue to work as it does now. Also, you should use the `bool` type if thats what you acutally want. I used `int` just as an example.

Comment: @OP : Also, you should declare and initialize your array dynamically, i.e `type** picture = //... SNIP : Array Init Stuff ...` and the call to the function would be: `leftk = left(picture, 200,200)`. This is assuming the array is of size 200x200 and `type` is the data type that you want: `bool` or `int` etc.

Comment: @Bhargav Bhat Thank you, I'll try to rebuild my project right now. If there're any questions, I'll ask again.

Comment: @Bhargav Bhat 200*200 is the size I declared firstly in the static array. The user decides what it'd be, that's why later I use the variable `size`

Comment: Wow, Great, It seems it's working. I'll test it for a while, but nevertheless, I'm very grateful.

Answer (score 2):

The usual solution is to wrap the array in a class; C doesn't handle
arrays very well, and C++ doesn't have any real support for 2D arrays in
its library either.  So you define either:

```
class Array2D
{
    std::vector<double> myData;
    int myColumnCount;
    int myRowCound;
    //  ...
};
```

with accessors which convert the two indexes using `i * myColumnCount +
j`, or:

```
class Array2D
{
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > myData;
    //  ...
};
```

with initialization logic ensure that all of the rows have the same
length.  The first is generally simpler and easier to understand; if you
want to increase the number of columns, however, the second is
significantly easier.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have five arrays to manage, so these methods may be quite a bit "bigger". So I hope to find a solution which will be simplier and smaller. But nevertheless, thanks for your support, I'll keep that method in mind.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "bigger".  Using `std::vector` instead of a `double*` will add a little bit, but typically only about the equivalent of 2 or 3 pointers.  Regardless of the size of the array.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm new to c++. So the std::vector means nothing to me. Of course, I can read about it, but if there's any other ways (except class wrapping), it'd be great

Comment: @user1131662 If you're new to C++, what other way do you know to create an array.  `std::vector` is the simplest and the safest, so it's the one which will be taught first in any decent C++ pedagogic text.  Long before `new` or `T[]`.

Comment: It seems we use different teaching styles. I haven't been told yet, what's happening in the heart of a compiler, but the things I have already used were `new` and `malloc`. But I've never heared of `std::vector` before.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options:

1. an array of arrays. For example, for `int` would be `int **a` which should be able to hold `n` arrays `new int *[n]`, then go with a `for` through them and initialized them `a[i] = new int[elems_per_line]`
2. a "packed" 1D array `int *a = new int[n * elems_per_line]`, where element (i, j) - 0-based is actually  `a[i * elems_per_line + j]`.
3. you can refine point 1, and have the 2D matrix be "curly" - with lines of different lengths, but you'll need an array to hold each length.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I've heared few things about the first way. It seems quite complicated to me, sorry. The second one is rather simple. I even tried to use it. But still the same problems with function. I've never hewared about the last one. So if I don't find a perfect solution, I'll read about this one more